# Regexp to keep values from json string

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I have a json string like this

```
"{\"firstName\": \"John\",\"lastname:\"smith\"}"
```

how to get the values (John,smith) from this string without using the parsejson, somthing like using regEx ?

Comment: What language are you using? i.e. what regexp flavor?

Comment: I can assure you that you're probably trying to handle your problem the wrong way.

Comment: @ricovox the question is tagged with `JavaScript`

Comment: Will your json always have exactly those two fields, or do you need a solution that would apply to any arbitrary json string?

Comment: @ricovox , yes i need a solution that would apply to any arbitrary json

Comment: @naomik ,my original js object has 100 field looping through will take sometime, so i just convert that object to string, now i can easily find the value is exist in string using some string manipulation.

Comment: @BalaKrishnan웃 instead of saying "I'm trying to get a particular solution working for my problem" why don't you write out your actual problem and show the code. That leaves the door open for multiple solutions; one of which is possible you didn't think of; one of which is possible is better than the one you're trying.

Comment: Let's see. You have a JSON string. Yet you don't want to use the built-in tools to parse JSON strings. Now, why on earth would that be?  This is sort of like saying, I have two numbers I want to add, but I don't want to use the `+` operator. Essentially, what you're saying is you want to build your own miniature, half-baked JSON parser for one extremely narrow application, using regexp's, of all things. What's wrong with this picture?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var name = the_string.match(/\{"firstName": "([^"]+)", "lastname": "([^"]+)"\}/),
var firstname = name[0],
    lastname  = name[1];
```

That being said, you should **always** handle JSON with JSON.parse. Really.

Comment: I think you mean `name[0]` and `name[1]`. There is no `match` variable defined.

Comment: i need a solution that would apply to any json string `firstName` and `lastname` is for eg

Comment: there's a syntax error and even with it fixed, this code doesn't generate the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a "flat" JSON string, meaning that there is no nesting of objects inside other objects, then you can write a regex to do it. Otherwise, if nesting IS present, then you need a full tokenizer/parser to do it. The reason is that regex only applies to [Regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), and JSON is more complicated and requries a **stack** which regex does not have.